# Get order of divs within div

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list of `DIV`'s is a container `DIV` similar to the below.

```
  <div id="ChainLinkList">
  <div class="chainSelect" id="L2176">jj</div>
  <div class="chainSelect" id="L2171">suby 3</div>
  <div class="chainSelect" id="L2170">suby 2</div>
  <div class="chainSelect" id="L2167">submenu</div>
  </div>
```

I would like to get the order of a particular `DIV` when clicked. I have tried the following

```
   $(".chainSelect").live("click", function() {
   var index = $(this).parent().index(".chainSelect");
   alert(index);
   .....
```

also

```
   $(".chainSelect").live("click", function() {
   var index = $('#ChainLinkList').parent().index(".chainSelect");
   alert(index);
   .....
```

But I just seem to get -1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just call `$(this).index();` to get the index of the clicked item inside it's parent:

```
$(".chainSelect").live("click", function() {
   var index = $(this).index();
   alert(index);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5ShLs/

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one:

`.live` is deprecated so it is better to use `.on()` handler

```
 $(document).on("click", ".chainSelect", function(){
   var index = $(this).index();
   alert(index);
 });
```

Comment: +1 for noticing `live`; -1 as `e.target` is not a good advice, though, as it has a different meaning. (total: 0 from me)

Comment: okay! but didn't get it why e.target is not a good advice? keen to learn more.

Comment: `e.target` could return a child of the intended element; this child has a very different position within _its_ parent than `this`. `e.target` is unrelated to the bound element or to the delegated element.

Comment: thanks jan Dvorak answer updated. will remember this. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You should change

```
$(".chainSelect").live("click", function() {
   var index = $(this).parent().index(".chainSelect");
   alert(index);
});
```

for:

```
$(".chainSelect").live("click", function() {
   var index = $(".chainSelect").index(this);
   alert(index);
});​
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eWtJu/)

Answer (score 0):

firstly..

```
    $('#ChainLinkList').parent()
```

in this you are calling parent of div chainlinklist , which here it self is parent of elemnt div you need.. so this will not do for you.

hence try this..

```
    $(this).index();
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to go to parent.. just get the index of your clicked element..

As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated.

```
$(".chainSelect").on("click", function() {
  var index = $(this).index();
  alert(index);
});​
```